# How to programatically hinder Windows from playing "Default Beep" sound when user clicks on disabled window (disabled via EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE))?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windowing

When a window is disabled via EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE), and the user clicks on it, then the "Default Beep" sound gets played. I don't want this to happen. How can I disable this behavior programatically for the current Process in C/C++ with Win32 code?

Answer (score 9):

The beep is generated by the default window processing of the `WM_SETCURSOR` message.

From docs for [WM_SETCURSOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-setcursor):

> If the low-order word of the lParam parameter is HTERROR and the high-order word of lParam specifies that one of the mouse buttons is pressed, DefWindowProc calls the MessageBeep function.

To prevent the beep, your window procedure should handle `WM_SETCURSOR` and not call `DefWindowProc` under those conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Funnily, in my runloop the breakpoint never gets hit:
         
`MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
 if (msg.message==WM_SETCURSOR)
 {
     int i=0; // <--- breakpoint here never gets hit!
 }

 TranslateMessage(&msg);
 DispatchMessage(&msg);
}`

Comment: @user3756504 *WM_SETCURSOR message is **sent** to a window* - you need handle this in window procedure. not in message loop

Comment: It's the same in my window procedure: WM_SETCURSOR is never received. BTW it's perfectly possible to do it as I did above, because the message loop dispatches to the window procedure. I can see the message with Spy++, but it never shows up in my Window Procedure or Message Loop, which is a baffling mistery. I have the feeling it has something to do with the fact that the window is disabled.

Comment: @user3756504 some messages is returned by `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` and you need call `DispatchMessage` for pass it to window procedure. another messages **direct** passed to window procedure by system and not returned by `Get[Peek]Message` - you never view it it message loop. `WM_SETCURSOR` direct passed to window procedure. even if it disabled. so some error in your code or you use wrong window

Comment: I stand corrected, indeed it works in window procedure. So the code to get rid of the MessageBeep now is: `if (msg==WM_SETCURSOR && LOWORD(lParam)==WORD(HTERROR) && IsWindowEnabled(hwnd)==FALSE) {return TRUE;}` Thanks for the help!